# Tool to create database diagram at SQL Azure

Tags: sql, azure, diagram

I need to use the create database diagram feature in SQL azure including full description of database tables and columns with keys, data types and relations.

What the best way to create diagram with tables, columns, keys, data types and relations as database diagrams do not seem to be available?

Comment: Easiest way I've used is by making an ERD with Visio.  But this question is a bit off-topic for this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Azure DB don't support diagrams in the same way 'normal' SQL Servers. If you're looking at workarounds or third-party tools, eg install SSDT, pull your model down, deploy to a local 'normal' dev server, create the diagram there, or Viso, Powerpoint, dbForge, Erwin, RedGate, Apex etc ... paper and pencil etc.

Comment: You can now do this in the preview version of 2016 SSMS.  google "SQL Server Management Studio preview" or try https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx